# Why my second request doesn't start?

Tags: ios

In my application, i have 2 class, one class for the portail ( RootViewController), and one class ( MainViewController ) ( in a navigation controller ) for sending request to a webservice.

When i start the application, i fill some textfield, then i push to my other class with this code:

```
MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initSpecial:0];
navController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
self.view.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject frame];
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

And i send my request to the webservice.

ConnectionDidFinishLoading receive the response from the server, everything is fine.

Then i want to come back, to my first class i do :

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
```

Now i try to repeat this process, but this time, when i am in the second class for sending my request, the request does not go completely and so does not go throw ConnectionDidFinishLoading.

I guess there is a problem, my request in the second class must be on a thread, and i probably do not move between class properly.

If you have an idea, please tell me.